# Configure Azure Event Grid for round-robin distribution

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Is it possible to configure an Azure Event Grid topic so that events are sent to subscribers on  a round-robin basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure Event Grid eventing Pub/Sub model distributes an event message in the **Fan-Out pattern**, such as that all active subscriptions will deliver a message to their destination event handler. There is no way to change this pattern to the load balancing.

However, you can subscribe with an event handler to the Azure Service Bus resource (queue/topic) which it will allow to load balanced between the ASB entities (queues/subscriptions).

Comment: Hey Roman, thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate it a little bit. Since subscribers cant be load balanced. If I have a Storage queue as subscriber and multiple region based Azure Trigger Functions that listens to this queue, any of the function will pick up the message from the queue.. so in a sense azure functions are automatically triggered based on some Azure criteria, but where does the load balancing happen here?

Comment: @gsb22, have a look at the Azure Service Bus document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview